# Why doesnt this MathUtils.random on the Y coordinate work?

Tags: arrays, random, libgdx

Its about the randomness at the Y coordinates between 0 and 1200 at which new houses (huis and rechterhuis) spawn

```
if (huisArray.size() > 0 && huisArray.get(0).getY() <= MathUtils.random(0, 1200)) {
        addNewHuis();
        addNewRechterHuis();

    }
```

Now the houses just fall until coordinate 0.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Are you running this in the `render` loop? That would result in a new random value in each frame and is probably not what you want.

Comment: Why does that minimizes the chance that the Y coordinate is below or equal to a random value between 0 and 1200 to zero? Because it never runs the code and it seems to me that if in each frame a new random value is chosen, additionally it should catch it

Comment: But you where should I put that code in then? @noone